# Can a $1 \times 1$ Matrix be any of these following type?

Tags: matrices, matrix-equations

I have some questions regarding $1 \times 1$ matrix as there was so much confusion on the $1 \times 1$ matrix. I just wanted to be sure.
They all are true/false questions basically.

Can a 1X1 Matrix be -

- Row Matrix?
- Column Matrix?
- Square Matrix?
- Diagonal Matrix?
- Scalar Matrix?
- Identity Matrix?
- Null Matrix?
- Upper Triangular Matrix?
- Lower Triangular Matrix?
- Symmetric Matrix?
- Skew Symmetric Matrix?

Answers:

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- All $1 \times 1$ matrices are square, diagonal, scalar, upper triangular, lower triangular, and symmetric.
- The only $1 \times 1$ matrix which is an identity matrix is $[1]$ .
- The only $1 \times 1$ matrix which is either skew-symmetric or null is $[0]$.

Comment: Thank you so much for help. Oh, just one more confirmation. 1x1 matrix can neither be row nor column matrix right? I have to be sure as I am making a web app.

Comment: @DevangJoshi: The opposite.  Any $1 \times 1$ matrix is both a row matrix and a column matrix.